# Usar o checkbox para ir para uma activity

Tags: android-activity, login, checkbox, firebase-database

Tudo bem?
Eu estou fazendo um projeto e me deparei com uma questão que não consigo solucionar.

Eu já criei uma activity com login e registro para um usuário, no entanto o meu modelo de negócio aceita dois tipos de usuários, homens ou* mulheres. Para isso eu criei um RadioGroup e RadioButton no registro pra poder separar no database do Firebase qual é qual. A questão é que se o usuário for homem eu quero que o botão de login e o registro levem para uma activity 1 por exemplo, no entanto se o usuário for mulher eu queria que o botão de login e o de registro levem para o activity 2.

Eu pensei em separar os dados do usuário de outras maneiras mas essa seria a ideal para mim, alguém sabe como fazer isso?
Obrigado

Comment: Fabrício, tudo bem? 
É interessante você deixar claro a sua dúvida no título, pois na listagem é o que chama a atenção de possíveis pessoas que podem dar a resposta. 
Uma susgestão: Como fazer para uma marcação em um RadioButton levar para uma activity 1 ou para o activity 2?

Comment: @egomesbrandao muito obrigado, iriei prestar mais atenção na próxima =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qual linguagem está usando ?
é so fazer um if .. se postar seu codigo te ajudo melhor, mas ficaria algo do tipo

```
if (checkboxMasculino.Checked)
{
 //codigo do botao masculino
}
else if (checkboxFeminino.Checked)
{
//codigo do botao feminino
}
```

Comment: Oi Sloan, você me ajudou demais!!!
Muito obrigado de verdade

Comment: Que nada! qualquer outra dúvida estamos aqui !